# Type 'HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

## How can I render an array of HTMLImageElement|s passed as props

Rather than passing an array of image paths to a child component, I want to pass an array of HTMLImageElement|s to the child component, so I can reference the file path in the parent component. But that gives me an error when I try to render them in the child component.

#### Parent component

```
import { ScrollImageSequence } from "../../scrollcontent/scrollImageSequence/ScrollImageSequence";

export const Image1ScrollSequence = () => {
    const images: HTMLImageElement[] = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const imgIdx = `${i}`.padStart(3, '0')
        images.push(<img src={require(`./images/image-sequence/image${imgIdx}.jpg`)} alt=""/> as unknown as HTMLImageElement);
    }
    return (
        <div className="image1Seq">
            <ScrollImageSequence {...images} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### Child component

This code throws a typescript error:
**Type 'HTMLImageElement' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.**

```
import './ScrollImageSequence.scss';
import React from 'react';

export const ScrollImageSequence = (images: HTMLImageElement[]) => {

    return images.map((img, idx) => (
            <React.Fragment key={idx}>
                { img }
            </React.Fragment>)
    )}
}
```

As long as I don't map the array, but return a single item, it works:

```
return (<>
  {images[0]}
</>)
```

I want to avoid passing just the image paths because then I would need to pass paths relative to the child component rather than the parent component. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: the type of `images` is `ReactNode[]`, and the type conversion (`as unknown as HTMLImageElement`) is wrong and not needed

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to use that array in a canvas element eventually which means that I need it as an HTMLImageElement. But passing the array as an array of ReactNode and doing the conversion in the child component works.